Jordan Canonical Form for a $4\times 4$ Matrix
I would like to prove the general result that,  given some matrix $M$ which has one eigenvalue $\lambda$ and one independent eigenvector $u_1$ associated to that eigenvalue, then the matrix $M$ is similar to the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{array}\right).$$
To do this, I believe it is because we can form a Jordan chain of independent generalized eigenvectors; finding independent $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4$ such that
$(M - \lambda I)u_2 = u_1$, $(M - \lambda I)u_3 = u_2$, $(M - \lambda I)u_4 = u_3$ where $u_1$ is the eigenvector.
This clearly immediately implies the result, but my question is about why these generalized eigenvectors exist.
I'm not sure how to prove that $u_2, u_3, u_4$ should exist -- why must there be solutions to these equations?
We know that $\dim (\text{Image}(A-\lambda I)) = 3$, and the kernel of $A - \lambda I$ must contain only span of $u_1$, but I'm not sure where to go from here in terms of formalizing that this Jordan chain exists.
Any help would be appreciated.

First off, you need $M$ to be a matrix over an algebraically closed field; otherwise the result isn't true. Here's a hint to begin with. Observe that: $u_1\in\ker(M-\lambda I)$, $u_2\in\ker(M-\lambda I)^2$ and so on.

I was sort of thinking this too. Taking $u_2 \in \ker(M-\lambda I)^2$, then $(M- \lambda I)^2 u_2 = 0$ so that $(M - \lambda I)u_2 \in \text{span}(u_1)$ giving what we want.
But then taking $u_3 \in \ker(M-\lambda I)^3$ then $(M - \lambda I)^3 u_3 = 0$ and so $(M - \lambda I)^2 u_3 \in \ker(M - \lambda I)^2$, but why should this imply that $(M - \lambda I) u_3 = u_2$? I would think that's the case if $\dim \ker(M- \lambda I)^2 = 1$ but I'm not sure why that is the case.

It can be shown that $$ \dim\ker(M-\lambda I)^j = j$$ for $j=1,2,3,4$. In other words, $$\ker(M-\lambda I)\subsetneq  \ker(M-\lambda I)^2\subsetneq  \ldots \subsetneq \ker(M-\lambda I)^4$$

Why the inclusions are strict? What would happen if $\ker(M-\lambda I)^j=\ker(M-\lambda I)^{j+1}$? Try to bring in a contradiction using the fact the the minimal polynomial of $M$ is $(x-\lambda)^4$ which we haven't used yet.

The point is that once $\ker(M-\lambda I)^j=\ker(M-\lambda I)^{j+1}$, it would follow that $\ker(M-\lambda I)^j=\ker(M-\lambda I)^k$ for all $k\geq j$. In particular, we know that $(M-\lambda I)^4=0$, so the chain of inclusions stabilizes from $j=4$ only and before that it must be strictly increasing; otherwise, we won't have $\dim \ker(M-\lambda I)^4=4$ and $\dim \ker(M-\lambda I)^3<4$ (which is implied from the minimal polynomial.)

Focus on the case $\lambda = 0$ (otherwise put $A=M-\lambda I$). The key point is to prove that $u_1\in \mathrm{Im}(M)$. Since $M_{| \mathrm{Im}(M)}$ still has all eigenvalues equal to $0$ and the kernel of $M$ is $1$-dimensional, we get $u_1\in \mathrm{Im}(M)$.
In particular, it does exist $u_2$ such that $Mu_2=u_1$. Similarly, $M_{| \mathrm{Im}(M^k)}$ has only eigenvalue $0$ and,as long as there is dimension, $u_1 \in \mathrm{Im}(M^k)$.
Eventually, you get the desired chain of generalized eigenvectors $u_1,...,u_4$. This basis corresponds to the Jordan block:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Did you mean $M_{| \mathrm{Im}(M^k)}$ instead of $M^k_{| \mathrm{Im}(M^k)}$?

In both cases what is written is true and sufficient to prove that $u_1\in \mathrm{Im}(M^k)$, but yes, it is more elegant with $M$. Thank you, I will edit it!

If I understand correctly, you have found $u_2$, $u_3$ and $u_4$ s.t. $Mu_2= u_1$, $M^2 u_3 = u_1$ and $M^3u_4=u_1$. How does this sufficiently prove that ${u_1,\ldots, u_4}$ will be a Jordan basis? I don't see how one will write down the matrix without knowing $Mu_3$ and $Mu_4$ in terms of coordinates.

I think I understand the idea now, but you need to prove that $\text{Im}(M^k)$ "has dimension" as long as $k\leq 3$ i.e., equivalently, $M^3\neq 0$. Then the existence of $u_2$, $u_3$ and $u_4$ will be justified. Now, since $M^3u_4=u_1$, we can choose $u_3=Mu_4$ and $u_2=Mu_3$ as the conditions $M^2 u_3=u_1$ and $Mu_2=u_1$ are met. By this choice, we now know that $Mu_1=0$, $Mu_k=u_{k-1}$ so we have all the coordinates to write a matrix. However, it still remains to show that $u_i$'s are linearly independent.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}$ Here's a more general and useful result:

Let $\displaystyle V$ be an $\displaystyle n$-dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $\displaystyle \mathbb{F}$. Let $\displaystyle T:\thinspace V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map such that $\displaystyle T$ has only one eigenvalue $\displaystyle \lambda $ and its corresponding eigenspace $\displaystyle \ker( T-\lambda I)$ is one-dimensional. Show that there is a basis $\displaystyle \mathcal B = \{v_{1} ,v_{2} ,\dotsc ,v_{n}\}$ of $\displaystyle V$ s.t. $\displaystyle Tv_{1} =\lambda v_1$ and  $\displaystyle Tv_{k} =v_{k-1} +\lambda v_{k}$ for $\displaystyle k=2,3,\dotsc ,n$.

In particular, if $n=4$, the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $\mathcal B$ will be:$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{array}\right).\tag*{}$
Let $\displaystyle L=T-\lambda I$.
What we want to show:

There is a basis $\displaystyle \{v_{1} ,v_{2} ,\dotsc ,v_{n}\}$ of $\displaystyle V$ s.t. $\displaystyle Lv_{1} =0$ and $\displaystyle Lv_{k} =v_{k-1}$ for $\displaystyle k=2,3,\dotsc ,n$.

Equivalently, there is a $\displaystyle v\in V$ s.t. $\displaystyle \left\{L^{n-1} v,\ L^{n-2} v,\dotsc ,v\right\}$ is a basis of $\displaystyle V$.


Given that $\displaystyle \dim\ker L=1$, by rank-nullity theorem, $\displaystyle \mathrm{rank} \ L=n-1$. 
Thus, there is a vector $\displaystyle v\in V$ s.t. $\displaystyle V=\mathbb{F} v\oplus \range( L)$.
Our goal is to show that the vectors $v$, $Lv$, $\ldots$, $L^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent and we'll be done.

Claim 1: $L^{n-1}v\neq 0 $.
Proof:
Since $\mathbb F$ is algebraically closed, any polynomial in $\mathbb F[x]$ splits into linear factors. In particular, $0$ being the only eigenvalue of $L$, the characteristic polynomial of $L$ is $x^n$. Using Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we note that $L^n=0$.
Using Sylvester's rank inequality, we see that:

$\rank L^2 \geq 2\rank L - n$ i.e., $\rank L^2\geq n-2$.
$\rank L^3 \geq \rank L^2 +\rank L - n$ i.e., $\rank L^3\geq n-3$.
By induction, it can be shown that $\rank L^{n-1} \geq 1$.

Thus, $L^{n-1}\neq 0$. However, since $L^n=0$, we have, $\ker(L^{n-1})\supseteq \range(L)$.
If it were the case that $L^{n-1}v=0$ then we would have $\ker(L^{n-1})\supset \mathbb Fv$. Recall that $V=\mathbb Fv\oplus \range(L)$ and we have both these summands contained in $\ker L^{n-1}$. Thus, $L^{n-1}=0$. (contradiction!)

Claim 2: $v$, $Lv$, $\ldots$, $L^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent.
Proof:
Suppose that $\lambda_0 v + \lambda_1Lv+\ldots+\lambda_{n-1}L^{n-1}v=0\tag{01}$ for some scalars $\lambda_i\in\mathbb F$.
Since $L^j=0$ for all $j\geq n$, applying $L^{n-1}$ on both sides of $(01)$, we get $\lambda_0 L^{n-1}v=0$. Using claim 1, $L^{n-1}v\neq 0$ so it must be that $\lambda_0=0$.
Now that the first term of $(01)$ is redundant, we have:
$\lambda_1Lv+\ldots+\lambda_{n-1}L^{n-1}v=0\tag{02}$
Applying $L^{n-2}$ on both sides of $(02)$, we get $\lambda_1L^{n-1}v=0$ and thereby, $\lambda_1=0$.
Using induction, you'll have $\lambda_0=\lambda_1=\ldots=\lambda_{n-1}=0$. $\blacksquare$
